# Python if len("string") <= 1: how to print the word? @codeacademy

Tags: python

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input ("Type the word you want to translate!")

def Pytranslator():
    if len("string") <= 1:
        print original
    else:
        return "empty"
```

I want to print the word if it has more than one (1) letter. I've tried

```
return True print original
```

Comment: `len("string")` will always be 6. You also seem to be confusing less than and greater than.

Comment: Is it a Codecademy exercise?

Comment: Yes it is a codeacademy exercise where u have to make your own translator.

Comment: I suggest you start with the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Answer (score 17):

You are testing the length of the *wrong thing*. Test `original` instead:

```
if len(original) <= 1:
    print original
```

`len("string")` is **always** going to be `6`, the number of characters in the value `"string"`:

```
>>> len("string")
6
```

Comment: Thanks for so fast replies, this site is really great but yet I don't get it.

`def Pytranslator():

if len(original) > 0:

print original

else:

print "empty"`

Nothing is printed!

Comment: Did you *call* `Pytranslator`?

Comment: No could you give my an example?

Comment: @AdamTodorovic: If you are still coming to grips with the very basics of programming, you really want to work your way through a few tutorials first. The [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) lists several options for you. Stack Overflow may not be the best place to ask for help with your issues.